# Maven - call command mvn help:effective-pom I get error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyVfV.png)I am working through  Maven tutorial, I create new maven project.  When trying to do a mvn help:effective-pom, I just seem to get this output

```
C:\Users\tari4>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\java\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_41, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\java\java-se-8u41-ri\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "x86", family: "windows"



D:\IT\maven_example>mvn help:effective-pom
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.3/maven-release-plugin-2.5.3.pom

[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.515 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-28T20:42:38+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\tari4\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: Probably a network issue.

Comment: You may need to set up a proxy for Maven or configure your firewall to allow Maven to download files form the Internet. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html.

Comment: Thank, guys! After I set the proxy for the maven. Maven was able to download files from the Internet